# One word for 'communication between two people'

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Can you please tell me what is the word for "***communication between two people***"?

Comment: Perhaps _Interaction_? Please more context!

Comment: To acquire a better answer I advise you to provide an example and if possible some more context. What is obvious to you can be confusing for people trying to answer the question. Are you referring to a face-to-face conversation? Telephone? Email? Or do you want a word covering all?  Is it two people exclusively or is that less important? None of this is clear, at least to me.

Comment: answers.com says it could be "_interpersonal communication_ " and "**Any communication between two people can be called a message**".

Comment: "Conversation"?

Comment: *Dialogue* (or *dialog*).

Answer (score 4):

A conversation between two people is a [*dialogue*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&source=hp&q=define+dialogue&oq=define+dialogue&gs_l=hp.3..0l10.1141.3307.0.5743.16.13.0.0.0.0.439.1880.0j5j1j1j1.8.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..9.7.1691.0.ZVIoNNDZyVo) (BrE) or *dialog* (AmE).

The word derives from the Greek for "two speakers".

Differentiating it from a monologue, which is a speech by one person.

Comment: While it is derived from "two", most dictionaries I know, (e.g. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dialogue), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dialogue)) define it as a conversation between "two or more" people/sides. It would be nice to have a word for exactly two sides.

Answer (score 0):

'Conversation' could be the word you are looking for. Additional context might help.

Comment: In itself this is a good answer. It would be even better if you added a reference to a good dictionary for 'Conversation' AND a block-quote of the relevant text found in the reference. That would make this answer more worthy of an up-vote.

Comment: Thanks Bookeater. I'm pretty new here, so I'm still learning the ropes of how answers are supposed to work here.

Comment: My pleasure. It is not straightforward, hence the hint. I had to learn as well a little while ago. If you do the update, I'll up-vote you and you will receive some reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "conversation"?

> **conversation**
>
> a talk, especially an informal one, between two or people in which news and ideas are exchanged

*Source: Google*